# How to automatically stop all started processes at the end of a powershell script

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script, that must start some background processes in order to automate a testing process.

```
# Start Server
$server=Start-Process -FilePath "server"  -PassThru

# Does some testing
# Eventually exit 1 will be called

# Stop Server
Stop-Process -Id $server.Id
```

In case an abnormal exit occured during my testing process I'm not able to stop all started processes with my script an I'm left with some dangling processes. How can I automatically kill all started processes of my script in case the script is exited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store all started processes information in an array. Then use [trap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_trap?view=powershell-7) which will run all your cleanup statements when terminating error occurs.

```
$proclist = @()
$proclist += Start-Process -FilePath "server" -PassThru

# testing

trap {
 foreach ($proc in $proclist) {
  Stop-Process -Id $proc.Id -Force -ErrorAction continue -Verbose
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I was not aware of trap.